# Can Azure AD B2C coexist with OWIN Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I want to use Azure AD B2C on my current ASP.NET MVC Web application without having to change too much.

The current app I'm working on uses `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` with `SignInManager` and `UserManager`.
It also uses `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` to get the currently signed in user. The users are stored in the database using the `dbo.AspNetUsers`. Also roles and rights are defined in the database. This is why it's a lot of work to switch to B2C completely and I'm hoping there's a way between.

Is it possible to link the 2 so that when you're logged in with Azure AD B2C, you will also be logged in on the current `Identity`?

I tried to get it to work, but I still get errors on `AntiForgeryToken` and `null` values at `System.Web.HttpContextBase.User.Identity`.

So first question: can Owin and B2C coexist in the way I need it to?

and secondly: is there a way to store the cookies for the previous way with Owin based on the emailaddress that's logged in with B2C?

EDIT:
Something else I tried is to redirect to an action where I can sign in the logged in user with my old authentication system too. It looks like this:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalB2CLogin()
    {
        if (ClaimsPrincipal.Current != null && ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.Any())
        {
            var email = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "emails").FirstOrDefault().Value;

            var user = await SignInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            
            SignInManager.SignIn(user, true, true);
            UserService.UpdateLastLogin(email);
            await UpdateClaims(user.Id);

            return RedirectToLocal("/");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Only problem is that if I add it like this:

[image: Redirect Uri Azure AD B2C]

Then it always redirects to that action. What I want is that B2C only redirects to this action after a successful login.

Does anyone have an idea how to configure that?

EDIT:
So basically I want the flow to go like this:

1. User comes on "/",
2. Because not logged in to OWIN Identity gets Redirected to "/Account/Login"
3. Then chooses to login with AAD B2C, which goes to the B2C url
4. User logs in on B2C login page
5. Logged in user gets redirected to "/Account/ExternalB2CLogin"
6. ExternalB2CLogin method also logs in to OWIN Identity, then redirects to "/"
7. Now the user is logged in to both B2C and OWIN Identity in the DB

Comment: I need to know it too.